# Use HEX to find file type

Tags: file, types, hex

I got a file and i don't know its type. I tried to run tools to get file type but that was of no use. When I open the file in hex editor it shows 00 hex value from starting to certain address(50 +linse). I know we can find type of file by seeing hex code of the file. But in this case it is showing 00. Can any one help how to find file type using hex value? Is there any way to obscure hex information so that file type can be hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux or Unix. You can type

> $ file filename

Or you can **use HEX signatures** of the file. refere this. http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

or use third party library "**magic.h**" library known as "**libmagic**" and use if in c++ like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "magic.h" 
int main() {   
  magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_CONTINUE|MAGIC_ERROR/*|MAGIC_DEBUG*/|MAGIC_MIME);
  magic_load(myt,NULL);   printf("magic output: '%s'\n",magic_file(myt,YOURFILENAME)); 
  magic_close(myt);

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I have not tried file command of linux. I am downloading Cygwin now to check that. I am using HEX signatur only but initial bytes of files are 00 which is not a signature. I have believe there is method to hide signature of a file. But i am not able to get source to confirm that.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not. The hex editor always shows real content (if it has permission to read the file at all).

Most binary file formats start with magic number, but not all of them. However bunch of nul bytes at the beginning looks more like the file is simply corrupt.

Comment: Is there anyway to find filetype even if file is corrupt. What do you mean by when you say "hex has permission to read the file" ?

Comment: @Mavenkp: hex is a format, it can't have permission for anything. Editor, on the other hand... If you don't have permission to read the file, it won't show up, obviously. But there are no permission for part of file, so either whole content comes up or nothing at all.

Comment: It depends on what file type it was. Some files have a characteristic structure inside, some don't. But even for the ones where it is possible it is quite difficult and the content may not be recoverable anyway.

Comment: Actually in a event i have recieved this file and task was to analyze the file. But to analyze the file I need to know type of the file. But with filetype finding tool was also not able to establish file type so I thought of doing analysis using hex editor.  I believe file is not corrupt but I am doing something wrong or I need some method to analyze the file

Comment: You'll need some context. Where does the file come from. Something to suggest formats it might be in.

Comment: It is part of a event. A challenge to test incident handling skills. I got the file as part of the activity. But i failed to get type of the the file only. "You"ll need some context" what that means.

Comment: That's enough context to know at least that the file **is corrupt**.